# $F[x^2,x^3] $ (subring of $F[x]$ with no linear term $x^1)$ is not a UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra

[My question pertains to this link](http://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/12/20/the-ring-of-polynomials-over-a-field-with-no-linear-term-is-not-a-ufd/) (the content of which has been included below in the most recent edit)

> > The ring of polynomials over a field with no linear term is not a UFD
>
> Let $F$ be a field. Prove that the subset $R \subseteq F[x]$
>   consisting of all polynomials whose linear coefficient is zero is a
>   subring. Prove also that $R$ is not a unique factorization domain.
>
> To show that $R$ is a subring, we need to see that it is closed under
>   subtraction and multiplication. To that end, let $\alpha = a_0 +
> > x^2a(x)$ and $\beta = b_0 + x^2 b(x)$ be in R. 
> Then $\alpha -
> > \beta$ = $(a_0 - b_0) + x^2(a(x) - b(x)) \in R$ and $\alpha \beta -
> > a_0b_0 + x^2(b_0a(x)x^2 + a_0b(x)x^2 + x^4a(x)b(x)) \in R$. 
> So $R$
>   is a subring.
>
> Next, we claim that $x^2$ and $x^3$ are irreducible in R. To see this,
>   note that no element of $R$ has degree $1$. If $x^2 = p(x)q(x)$ factors in
>   $R$, then computing the degree of both sides we have $\mathsf{deg}(p(x))
> > + \mathsf{deg}(q(x)) = 2$. Since neither of these degrees is $1$, one must be $0$, so that without loss of generality, $p(x)$ is constant and
>   thus a unit. So $x^2$ is irreducible. Similarly, $x^3$ is irreducible
>   because if two nonnegative integers sum to $3$ then one of them must be
>   $0$ or $1$. So $x^2$ and $x^3$ are irreducible in $R$.
>
> Now $x^6 = x^2x^2x^2 = x^3x^3$, so that $x^6$ has at least two distinct
>   irreducible factorizations in $R$. Thus $R$ is not a unique factorization
>   domain.

(We are not required to show that this is indeed a subring, only that it is not a unique factorization domain.)

I understand (more or less) everything stated, through "Now $x^6 = x^3x^3 = x^2x^2x^2$".

Does this conclude the proof because we have found an element in R with two distinct factorizations?

How did we use the requirement that the linear terms be zero?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not enough to just find two distinct factorizations (after all, in $\mathbb{Z}$, you have $8 = 2\times2\times 2$ **and** $8=2\times 4$). What is important is that you find two distinct factorization *into irreducibles* (that are not related via multiplication by units; so again, $4=2\times 2 = (-2)\times(-2)$ does not disprove that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a UFD).

Here, you need to show that both $x^2$ and $x^3$ are irreducibles in this ring, before you can conclude from $x^6 = x^3x^3 = x^2x^2x^2$ that you have two (essentially) distinct factorizations of $x^6$ into irreducibles. And in order to prove that both $x^2$ and $x^3$ are irreducible in this ring you *will* have to use that the linear terms of the elements of this ring are zero.

The link you provide proves this before exhibiting the factorization; when it says "since neither of these is degree $1$", **that's** where they are using there is no linear term.

Comment: That I am missing such obvious statements is evidence of how lost I am :(... thanks Arturo. I am feeling less lost!

Answer (score 1):

Below are sketches of $3$ simple proofs that $\rm R = F[x^2,x^3]\,$ is not a UFD.

---

$[\![1]\!]\ \ \ \rm (x^2)^3 = (x^3)^2\ $ is a nonunique factorization into irreducibles, because the irreducibles $\rm\,x^2,\ x^3\,$ are nonassociate, i.e.  $\rm\ x^3\nmid x^2\ $ (by degree compare) and $\rm\, x^2\nmid x^3\, $ by $\rm\ x\not\in R $

---

$[\![2]\!]\ \ \ \rm\,R\,$ is not a $\rm UFD$ by $\rm\,x^2\,$ is irreducible but not prime, since $\rm\ x^2\, | \,(x^3)^2\ $ but $\rm\ x^2\nmid x^3$

---

$[\![3]\!]\ \ \ \rm UFD \Rightarrow$ integrally closed, but $\rm\,R\,$ is not:  $\rm\ y^2 - x^2\ $ has the root $\rm\ y = x^3/x^2 = x\not\in R,\,$ i.e. in simpler language: the [Rational Root Test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/658058/242) fails, but [it holds in a UFD](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4343557/242).

---

**Note** $ $  $\rm R\,$ is a subring follows easily by the [subring test:](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/40677/242) it contains $1$ and it closed under subtraction and multiplication, since $\rm\,f'(0) = 0 = g'(0)\,$ $\Rightarrow$  $\rm\,(f-g)'(0) = f'(0)-g'(0) = 0\,$ and $\rm\,(fg)'(0) = f'(0)\, g(0) + f(0)\,g'(0) = 0.$

Answer (score 1):

$F[x^2,x^3]$ is an integral domain with field of fraction $F(x)$. $x \in F(x)$ is integral over  $F[x^2,x^3]$ but not in $F[x^2, x^3]$. So it is not a UFD as any UFD is integrally closed domain.

Comment: This was already mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because no element of $R$ has degree $1$ which shows that $x^2$ and $x^3$ are irreducible in $R$.

Comment: (Facepalm)... I just logged back onto M-SE after realizing this! Thanks :)