# Is it Integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is $ \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt {D}]$ an integral domain ?

My solution:

$$ \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt {D}]=\{ a+b\sqrt {D} , a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

No ,

Suppose $\mathbb {Z}[\sqrt {D}]$ is integral domain then 
Let $a, b \in \mathbb {Z}[\sqrt {D}]$
Where$ a=x +y\sqrt {D}$

$||a||$ $||b||=0$
$ \implies ||a|| =0 or ||b||=0$

If $||a|| =0  $then $x^2-y^2D=0$ 
So $x= y\sqrt {D}$

then it is contradiction  when D is not perfect  square  , so it isn't  Integra domain.

If D is prefect square then it is integral domain

Can anyone tell me if it is true or not?
if not , any hint for solve ? 
Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming $\;D\in\Bbb Z\;$ , too...right?

Comment: @DonAntonio No D  May be irrational number or rational

Comment: Really? Then you're probably *not* taking this  stuff from algebraic number theory, right? And even more interesting: what **then** do you mean by $\;\left\|a\right\|\;$ ??

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1149283/is-r-an-integral-domain?rq=1).

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Observe that no matter what $\;D\in\Bbb Q\;$ is, we always have $\;\Bbb Z(\sqrt D)\subset \Bbb C\;$ ...

Comment: But $\mathbb {Z} (\sqrt {D}} is not complex number

Comment: @user508518 It is not even a number but a ring. Yet **any** element in that ring is , for sure, a complex number.

Comment: So is it integral domain?

Comment: @user508518 If it **always** contained in a *field*, what do you think?

Comment: It is integral domain because field

Comment: @user508518 No, this ring is not a field. Take $D=1$ for example.