# Showing a set of fractions is a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number. Let $R$ be the subset of all rational numbers $m / n$ such that $n \neq 0$ and $n$ is not divisible by $p$. Show that $R$ is a ring.

My Proof-trying.

$R1$. Associativity for under addition is clear.

$R2$. $\dfrac {m} {n}+0=0+\dfrac {m} {n}$, so there exist the identitiy element for under addition.

$R3$. $\dfrac {m} {n} + \dfrac {-m} {n}=\dfrac {-m} {n} +  \dfrac {m} {n}$, so there exist inverse element.

$R4$. $\dfrac {m} {n} + \dfrac {m'} {n'}=\dfrac {m'} {n'}+\dfrac {m} {n}$, so commutativity.

So $R$ is an additive abelian group.

$R5$. $\dfrac {m} {n} ( \dfrac {r} {s} + \dfrac {t} {v})=\dfrac {mr} {ns} + \dfrac {mt} {nv}$ and $( \dfrac {r} {s} + \dfrac {t} {v})\dfrac {m} {n}=\dfrac {rm} {sn}+\dfrac {r} {s}+\dfrac {tm} {vn}$

$R6.$ $R$ is associativity for under multiplication, clear.

$R7.$ $1 \dfrac {m} {n}=\dfrac {m} {n} 1 = \dfrac {m} {n}$, so there exist identity element for under multiplication.

**Can you check my answer? If false, can you write true answer?**

Comment: this subset doesn't seem well-defined, e.g if p=2 it doesn't contain 2/6 but does contain 1/3

Comment: @MatthewTowers Can you write an answer?

Comment: @MatthewTowers that can be fixed by insisting that the rational number can be written _in lowest terms_ as $m/n$, where $p$ does not divide $n$.

Comment: @Apache You have the right working, you just need more justification. In your stages R5 and R6, how do you know that the answers you get (eg $\frac{mr}{ns} + \frac{mt}{nv}$) belong to the subset $R$?
_Hint:_ write them as single fractions (eg $\frac{vmr + smt}{nvs}$)

Comment: In case you're interested @Apache, the ring you are constructing is called the "localisation of $\mathbb{Z}$ at $p$", which I usually see denoted $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$

Answer (score 5):

More generally, suppose our denominator set $S$ is a set of integers $\neq 0$  closed under multiplication and $\,1\in S\,$ (true here because integers coprime to $\,p\,$ are closed under multiplication by Euclid). Let $\,R\,$ be the set of all rationals writable in form $\,a/s,\ a\in\Bbb Z,\, s\in S.$

By the [subring test](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/40677/242) $\,R\subseteq \Bbb Q\,$ is a subring if it contains the unit $\,1\,$ of $\,\Bbb Q\,$ and it is closed under multiplication
and subtraction. $R$ contains $1/1 = 1\,$ by $\,1\in S,\,$ and $\,\frac{a}b,\frac{c}d\in R\Rightarrow \frac{a}b\frac{c}d = \frac{ac}{bd}\,$ and $\,\frac{a}b-\frac{c}d = \frac{ad-bc}{bd}\,$ are both in $\,R,\,$ since $S$ is closed under multiplication

**Remark** $ $ This "$\rm\color{#0a0}{partial}$" fraction ring construction works very generally -  see [localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_(commutative_algebra)). The classical case of the fraction field is the special case when the denominator set is the set of $\rm\color{#c00}{all}$ nonzero elements in an integral domain (it generalizes to non-domains by inverting $\rm\color{#c00}{all}$ non-zero-divisors, yielding the [$\rm\color{#c00}{total}$ ring of fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_ring_of_fractions)).

Any proof that verifies all the ring axioms is of course correct, but is wasteful since we can trivially infer that these axioms persist in all subsets of $\Bbb Q$ due to their logical form (syntax), viz. all ring laws are *universal* laws ("identities") - those of form $\,\forall x,y\in \Bbb Q\!:\ f(x,y) = g(x,y)\,$  whose truth clearly persists in subsets. This fails for more general axioms, e.g. inverse existence $\,\forall x\neq 0\,\color{#c00}{\exists y}\!:\ x\color{#c00}y = 1,\,$ i.e. subsets may omit $\rm\color{#c00}{roots},\,$ so subrings of fields (e.g. $\Bbb Z\subset \Bbb Q)\,$ need not be fields.