# Is there a name for the subset of the rationals where the denominator is coprime with a specific integer?

Tags: rational-numbers

Considering a natural integer $n$ ($n>1$). Is there a name for the set of all rationals which can be written as $p/q$ with $p$ and $q$ integers and $q$ coprime with $n$ ?

For $n=2$ it would be all the rationals with an odd denominator, for $n=3$ all rationals whose denominator is not congruent to zero mod 3, etc.

Comment: This is probably a bit too abstract for your purposes, but there's a notion called *localization* where we have a structured way of adjoining denominators to a ring. If $S$ is the set of numbers sharing no prime factors with $n$, then $S^{-1}\mathbf{Z}$ is the set you are describing. If I wished to avoid all the machinery involved in this, I would probably just give such a set a name; e.g. $X_n$.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4128551/242). There is no standard name (but there is standard notation using localization language).