# Proving that the sum of a linear combination in R is an ideal in R (for commutative rings)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Doubt: In this proof I know that we need to show that I is a subgroup of (R, +) and is I is closed under multiplication. How does the first part of the proof show the subgroup property? I did not understand the
$$(r_1a_1-r'_1a_1) + (r_2a_2-r'_2a_2)+\cdots+(r_na_n-r'_na_n) = (r_1-r'_1)a_1+(r_2-r'_2)a_2+\cdots + (r_n-r'_n)a_n\in I$$
part, why are we performing a subtraction?

---

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and let $a_{1}, a_{2}, \ldots, a_{n} \in R$. Then
$$
I=\left\langle a_{1}, a_{2}, \ldots, a_{n}\right\rangle=\left\{r_{1} a_{1}+r_{2} a_{2}+\cdots+r_{n} a_{n} \mid r_{i} \in R\right\}
$$
is an ideal of $R$ called the ideal generated by $a_{1}, a_{2}, \ldots, a_{n}$.
\PROOF.
If $r_{1} a_{1}+r_{2} a_{2}+\cdots+r_{n} a_{n}, r_{1}^{\prime} a_{1}+r_{2}^{\prime} a_{2}+\cdots+r_{n}^{\prime} a_{n} \in I$,
$\left(r_{1} a_{1}+r_{2} a_{2}+\cdots+r_{n} a_{n}\right)-\left(r_{1}^{\prime} a_{1}+r_{2}^{\prime} a_{2}+\cdots+r_{n}^{\prime} a_{n}\right)=$
$$
\left(r_{1} a_{1}-r_{1}^{\prime} a_{1}\right)+\left(r_{2} a_{2}-r_{2}^{\prime} a_{2}\right)+\cdots+\left(r_{n} a_{n}-r_{n}^{\prime} a_{n}\right)=
$$
$$
\left(r_{1}-r_{1}^{\prime}\right) a_{1}+\left(r_{2}-r_{2}^{\prime}\right) a_{2}+\cdots+\left(r_{n}-r_{n}^{\prime}\right) a_{n} \in I .
$$
If $r_{1} a_{1}+r_{2} a_{2}+\cdots+r_{n} a_{n} \in I$ and $r \in R$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
r\left(r_{1} a_{1}+r_{2} a_{2}+\cdots+r_{n} a_{n}\right)=\left(r_{1} a_{1}\right.&\left.+r_{2} a_{2}+\cdots+r_{n} a_{n}\right) r=\\
&\left(r r_{1}\right) a_{1}+\left(r r_{2}\right) a_{2}+1 \cdots+\left(r r_{n}\right) a_{n} \in I .
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore $I$ is an ideal.

Comment: In general, if $G$ is a group then a nonempty (by the way, this wasn't check in the proof) subset $H\subseteq G$ is a subgroup if and only if $x,y\in H$ implies $x^{-1}y\in H$. When the operation of $G$ is addition, this means that we need to have $x-y\in H$ for all $x,y\in H$. So that's what is done in this proof.

Comment: They are implicitly using a [subgroup test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test), just as in the [subring test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/40685/242).