# Why is $S$ a subring of $R$ if it is nonempty and is closed under subtraction and multiplication?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am currently reading *A First Course in Rings and Ideals* and the theorem for subring states:

Let $R$ be a ring and $S$ be a nonempty subset of $R$. Then, $S$ is a subring
of $R$ if and only if

1. $a, b \in S$ implies $a - b \in S$ (closure under differences),
2. $a, b \in S$ implies $ab \in S$ (closure under multiplication).

Why did theorem use "closure under differences" instead of "closure under addition?
Also, does this theorem also imply that subrings are closed under addition?

Thanks!

Comment: Because that way you also get the zero and the additive inverses.

Comment: See e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/40685/242) in the first dupe. Beware that in the second dupe this is (wrongly) called the "ideal test".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if $S \subseteq R$ is closed under subtraction, then it is also closed under addition.

*Proof.* Let $a, b \in S$ be arbitrary. Then $0 = b-b \in S$, so $-b = 0-b \in S$. Now $a + b = a - (-b) \in S$. $\square$

However, the converse is not true! There can exist subsets of $R$ which are closed under addition but not subtraction. For example, $\mathbb{N} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$. So, if the theorem said "closed under addition" instead of "closed under subtraction", it would be wrong.

---

Let me also make a more philosophical point:

> does this theorem also imply that subrings are closed under addition?

This question doesn't really make sense to ask. Subrings *are* closed under addition, by definition (Definition 1-4 in your book, if I'm not mistaken). The theorem does not tell you anything new about subrings -- instead, it gives you an efficient way to check if a subset of a ring is a subring. If this doesn't quite make sense yet, that's ok! Reread this page of your book and then go talk to your professor about it.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: Apologies, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just recall the definition of subring (or def of ring if you've forgotten):
let $(R, +, \cdot )$ be ring, $A\subset R$ is called a subring of $R$ if $(A, +, \cdot)$ is also a ring.

If $A$ is subring, it is clear that 1 and 2 are correct.

on the other hand, 1 implies $A$ is a subgroup of $R$ with respect to addtion. 2 implies $A$ is closed under multiplication. Hence you can check that $(A, +, \cdot)$ is a ring straight from definition.

I guess your confusion mostly comes from the following theorome:

Let $(G, \cdot)$ be group, then $H\subset G$ is subgroup iff $\forall x, y\in A, xy^{-1}\in H$

come back to this thm and you'll figure out why it's subtraction not addtion.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: sry, Idk about that. I'll be aware of such situations next time!